# Push a git-svn local repo to a different svn remote repo that already exists

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to integrate two svn repos. One is a kind of fork of the other. But it's not exactly a fork so i can't find a common point.

I've cloned both repos in one local git-svn repo, each repo in one branch, and i have already integrated both repos but know i need to push the changes to one of the original repos. I trying to figure the best workflow for upload the changes maintaining the history. I think that it should be something like this:

```
# Move the trunk of the remote repo to a branch
$ svn move svn+ssh://host.example.com/repos/project/trunk svn+ssh://host.example.com/repos/project/branches/NAME_OF_BRANCH -m "Creating a branch of project"

# Make a commit that explains the change that is going to happen

# Change to the branch that tracks the remote repo, and fetch the changes
$ git checkout myBranch
$ git svn rebase

# The folder should be empty at this point

# Upload the local changes to the trunk of the remote repo
$ git merge integrationBranch

# ¿rewrite the history?

# Upload it
$ git svn dcommit
```

I can't find a [better explanation](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2010/2/10/22879) but i think that git svn dcommit uses git-svn-id of the last commit to figure which is the url to push, so i guess that in some point i should rewrite the history, but i don't know how.

Also if anyone can provide a way to make a test before really upload the changes will be great.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found how to rewrite the history [based on this post](http://translate.org.za/blogs/wynand/en/content/changing-your-svn-repository-address-git-svn-setup). To change the git-svn-id i use:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter  'sed "s/git-svn-id:.*//g"' myBranch
```